# Rounded Custom UIButton does not exhibit the touch effect

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I'm creating a custom UIButton like the following:

```
public class RoundButton : UIButton
{
    public override void LayoutSubviews()
    {
        base.LayoutSubviews();

        Layer.CornerRadius = Bounds.Height / 2;
    }

    public override void TouchesBegan(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
    {
        this.Highlighted = true;
        base.TouchesBegan(touches, evt);
    }

    public override void TouchesEnded(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
    {
        this.Highlighted = false;
        base.TouchesEnded(touches, evt);
    }
    public override void TouchesCancelled(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
    {
        this.Highlighted = false;
        base.TouchesCancelled(touches, evt);
    }
}
```

I'm using like this:

```
    var submitButton = new RoundButton();

    submitButton.Frame = new CGRect(10, 170, w - 20, 44);

    submitButton.SetTitle(Utilities.GetLocalizedString("connection"), UIControlState.Normal);
    submitButton.SetTitleColor(UIColor.White, UIControlState.Normal);
    submitButton.BackgroundColor = new UIColor(red: 1.00f, green: 0.37f, blue: 0.00f, alpha: 1.0f);
    submitButton.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth;

    EventHandler p = async (sender, e) =>
    {
        Logging.Debug(@"Submit button pressed");
        await Application.m_webAccess.LoginAsync(usernameField.Text, passwordField.Text, Application.MyCancellationTokenSource.Token).ContinueWith(t => LoginResult(t.Result)).ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: true);

    };

    submitButton.TouchUpInside -= p;
    submitButton.TouchUpInside += p;
```

Despite the fact that the Touches* overrides are called, there is visually no touch effect visible.

What is wrong here?

Comment: You seem to be changing the highlighted bool, may I know what exactly are you trying to do here? Are you trying to add like a ripple clicked effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add Animation on the button touch event to achieve the effect as you need . For example , set the BackgroundColor gradient .

```
public class RoundButton : UIButton
{
    public override void LayoutSubviews()
    {
        base.LayoutSubviews();

        Layer.CornerRadius = Bounds.Height / 2;
    }

    public override void TouchesBegan(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
    {
        this.Highlighted = true;

        SetAnimation(UIColor.LightGray);

        base.TouchesBegan(touches, evt);
    }

    public override void TouchesEnded(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
    {
        this.Highlighted = false;

        SetAnimation(UIColor.Orange);

        base.TouchesEnded(touches, evt);
    }
    public override void TouchesCancelled(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
    {
        this.Highlighted = false;
        base.TouchesCancelled(touches, evt);
    }


    void SetAnimation(UIColor color)
    {
        UIView.BeginAnimations(null);
        UIView.SetAnimationDuration(1.0);
        UIView.SetAnimationTransition(UIViewAnimationTransition.None, this, false);

        this.Layer.BackgroundColor = color.CGColor;

        UIView.CommitAnimations();
    }

}
```

For more details about Animations in iOS you could check the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/graphics-animation-ios/core-animation) .